# How to download Azure blobs in Angular with a key or with a connection string

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to download Azure files with a connection string or key, and perform the process in Angular

When I try to use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob library in Angular it does not recognize the connection type fromConextionString

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to download Azure files with a
>   connection string or key, and perform the process in Angular

Considering the Angular code executes in the browser (i.e. client side), connecting to a storage account using an **Account Connection String** (`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=accountKey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`) is not allowed as it exposes your account key to the client.

What you will have to do is use a **Shared Access Signature (SAS) Connection String** (`BlobEndpoint=https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=sasString`).

More information about this can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest#fromconnectionstring-string--storagepipelineoptions-.